# How to config yii2 urlManager rules with language GET parameter and hide Controller name

Tags: php, yii2

For my advanced yii2 project, i added this rule to the common config to support multilanguage view:

```
'<lang:\w+>/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

This is working fine, and localhost/en/site/about point to localhost/site/about.

Now i want to hide site controller in the url. I try this:

```
'<lang:\w+>/<alias:\w+>' => '<lang:\w+>/site/<alias>',
```

But it does not work. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Try `'<lang:\w+>/<alias:\w+>' => '<lang>/site/<alias>'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ngô Văn Thao. I try with this rules: '<lang:\w+>/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>', 
                '<lang:\w+>/<alias:\w+>' => '<lang>/site/<alias>', when I click on the About link, it shows me an Error 404 not found (http://localhost/en/about)

Comment: what controller are not found ? (Yii debug)

Comment: Does not find SiteController. The original url is http://localhost/en/site/about. This url works if I have only this rule: '<lang:\w+>/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>', If i add the following rule: '<lang:\w+>/<alias:\w+>' => '<lang>/site/<alias>', yii converts the url from about to http://localhost/en/about, but it does not work and displays an Error 404.